# Image Rotate animation Looping not work on android

Tags: android

I want to rotate imageview with continuously looping on android.my code rotate is working perfectly with out set repeat mode.if i set repeat mode repeat animation not working but, imageview statically rotate some angle and i want loop rotate animation any one can help me with greatly appreciated!

here's animation xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromDegrees="45"
  android:toDegrees="45"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="50%"
  android:duration="100"
  android:startOffset="0"
/>
```

here's my java class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AnimationActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ImageView my_image;
    AnimationListener listener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        listener = new AnimationListener() {
            @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
            @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                System.out.println("End Animation!");
                //load_animations();
            }
        };

        my_image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_img);
        load_animations();



    }
    void load_animations()
    {
        new AnimationUtils();
        Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotation);
        rotation.setRepeatCount(-1);
        rotation.setRepeatMode(2);
        rotation.setAnimationListener(listener);
        my_image.startAnimation(rotation);
    }

}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

finally,i got solution try below xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromDegrees="0"
  android:toDegrees="360"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="50%"
  android:duration="2000"
  android:repeatMode="reverse"
  android:repeatCount="infinite"
  android:startOffset="0"
/>
```

here's my class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AnimationActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ImageView my_image;
    AnimationListener listener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        listener = new AnimationListener() {
            @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
            @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                System.out.println("End Animation!");
                //load_animations();
            }
        };

        my_image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_img);
        load_animations();



    }
    void load_animations()
    {
        new AnimationUtils();
        Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotation);
        rotation.setAnimationListener(listener);
        my_image.startAnimation(rotation);
    }

}
```

That's the code is working perfectly!

My problem was solved!

Answer (score 0):

After researching through the answers from internet, I found a solutions which works perfectly for me. (And yes, the repeatCount and repeatMode is extremely buggy when used together with animationSet).

anim_rotate_fade.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:ordering="together" >

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="3000"
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:valueTo="360"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="3000"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="0.3"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="3000"
        android:propertyName="y"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:valueFrom="380"
        android:valueTo="430"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

In activity:
(Solve it by introducing a slight delay after animation ended).

```
ImageView starlightImageView = new ImageView(this);
starlightImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.starlight);
final AnimatorSet animate = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.anim.anim_rotate_fade);
AnimatorListenerAdapter animatorListener = new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                animate.start();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
};
animate.setTarget(starlightImageView);
animate.addListener(animatorListener);
```

There are a lot of classes you would like to research on, but currently I'm using objectAnimator which is highly flexible. I wouldn't recommend to use Animation or AnimationUtils:

- Animation
- AnimationUtils
- Animator
- AnimatorInflater
- AnimatorListener
- AnimatorListenerAdapter